# Is it possible to have shine or glint movement animation on button with coding? (not gif or similar way)

Tags: java, android, animation, button

I want to have a button with a shine or glint movement animation on it.
not so much complicated just a moving shine line on a button.
is it possible with Animation in java in the android studio or not?

Comment: what you had tried so far ?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma actually noting, i just have a simple button with a color background like this:             <gradient
                android:endColor="@color/green1"
                android:startColor="@color/green2"
                android:angle="270" />

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways doing it but I will give the method that I use more often...

Create shapes with a gradient of horizontal and vertical line...

**vert_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#555994"
        android:centerColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#555994"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners
        android:radius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

**hor_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#555994"
        android:centerColor="#ffffff"
        android:startColor="#555994"
        android:type="linear" />

    <corners
        android:radius="0dp"/>

</shape>
```

Then create a selector in order to make button's background change when it is pressed and it will give you shine effect...

**shine_line.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/line_vert" /> <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/line_hor" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

> Last set it to your button background.

```
   <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shine_line"/>
```

It will work like a charm.